# MSVC vs Toolset

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have Visual Studio 15.9.10.
It lets me choose different Platform Toolsets: v140 and v141.

With v141, I can choose different C++ Standards: C++14, C++17 and C++Latest (why not with v140?)

How does the `_MSC_VER` (1916) come into all of this? What does it signify?

Comment: You probably had VS2015 installed on that machine, it used toolset v140.  For VS2017 the normal selection is v141.  MSC_VER simply reports [the compiler version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering)

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand what these things do and what they don't do.